# Issue with mail server sending emails to same server does not work in cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp

I am trying to send email (using cakephp) to same server but to a different id like no-reply@example.com to user1@example.com, user2@example.com. There is no error messages thrown but mail is not received by user1 and user2, where as when I send email from same no-reply@example.com to my yahoo id and vice versa(from my yahoo id to no-reply@example.com) it works well. Unable to figure out why the mail is not sent to same server alone. could any one help me in resolving this?

Comment: So user1 and user2 are not receiving emails?? How about sendin email from user2 -> yahoo and yahoo -> uer2/1. What happens?

Comment: actually no-reply is also from the same server, it is possible to send from their id but unable to receive mails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your help. I had figured out the issue, we have to remove our domain name from "mydestination" in /etc/postfix/main.cf and reload postfix using /etc/init.d/postfix reload. That works! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are supplying the email addresses as an array.

Second, I've had problems with this when using SMTP details. Try sending without populating the SMTP login details - if the script is on the same server as the mail server, it should pick up the default login.

You can also `debug($this->Email);` to try to get a look at the settings.

Comment: thanks! we are using postfix and not smtp. mail( $em, $subject, $message, $headers ); - this is how I send and I am not sure how to pass as array. And we send only one mail at a time and it is received as input from user through a form. I believe I am clear in explaining